# How to filter out matching usernames form firestore database in flutter social media application

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, flutter-dependencies

So I am creating a Social media appliation with the help of flutter. And in search user page I had created a page where user can search their friends with their Profile names. And in this I used:-

Future allUsersProfile = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").where("profileName", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: str).get();

By this  I get all the matching profile names.

But when I enter their last name their is no result.

Also I want to convert profile names to lower case and then match.

Also I want that if the search name is in between the saved profile name(for example :-  I want to search "arsh" form "Harsh", I can't find the result.
) then also it should give this particular result,

So I want idea that how big social media companies search users.

Can anyone can help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are storing profileName in the same field(including first and last names). i.e, in your Firebase user document, `profileName` combines both first and last names. You need to do the following:

1- In your Firebase `users` collection, store a new field for every document called something like 'searchName'.

2- When you store your user info, use this code to to convert `profileName` into `searchName`:

```
String profileName = 'Huthaifa Muayyad`;
String searchName = profileName.toLowerCase().replaceAll(' ', ''); 
//The .toLowerCase method converts it all to lower case
//The replaceAll, removes the whitespaces. 
//Notice the difference between  (' ', ''). 
//This will result in Huthaifa Muayyad => huthaifamuayyad
```

3- Save both fields in firebase along with all the other info when you create the user.

4- Assuming that `str` is the input you are getting from the search field, modify your Firebase query to look like this:

```
Future allUsersProfile = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").where("searchName", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: str.toLowerCase().replaceAll(' ', '')).get();
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but if I want to search "arsh" form "Harsh", I can't find the result.?

Comment: This was not mentioned in your question, as you stated your search is working for first name.

Comment: yes I did't stated. Can you help me with this?